# What sort of wave (on the EM spectrum) should I use to detect a cavity on an asphalt surface with a sensor moving at 80 km/hr?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Let's say that I am walking blindfolded and I have a device in my hand. I am holding the device 2 feet from the ground. I need the device to detect when the ground is suddenly very different from the rest of the ground, specifically when there is a cavity (absence of ground). Assume the ground is made of asphalt. What sort of wave would my device need to shoot out in such a way as to be able to detect a change in the ground?

Comment: Look up ground-probing radar. Used a great deal by authorities looking for buried dead bodies and also by archaeologists.

Comment: I guess I should specify that I don't really need to probe ***below*** the surface. I'm really just looking at the surface of the road and if the signal takes longer to come back to the sensor, then there must be a cavity, i.e. a pothole.

Comment: What would work better in this scenario: radar or lidar?

Comment: Ah that makes a big difference. From what distance? Have a look at structured light 3d scanning and then see whether that fits your needs. I'd you want to ask more specific questions about it, I've designed these systems before. It sounds like what you need

Comment: See this link here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured-light_3D_scanner

Comment: The distance is about 30 inches or 0.762 meters

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance how well do you think these scanners would work for ***cavities***, i.e. holes in the ground of irregular shape?

Comment: It should still work. The boundary of a cavity where there is an abrupt change in level as in a scored out pothole will show up as a discontinuity in the fringes. It's very similar to an interferogram if you put an optical flat partially into the beam: the flat shows up through the discontinuity. There are well developed algorithms, very like the phase unwrapping algorithms in interferometry, that will give you a depth profile. You'll need a scheme with several fringe sources placed at different positions relative to the sensor. The technology is very well developed: you should be able ...

Comment: ... to buy something off the shelf for your application. See [here](https://www.objective3d.com.au/handheld-3d-scanners/) or [her](http://www.toptenreviews.com/computers/scanners/best-3d-scanners/). LIDAR would also work very well in your application, but I suspect that there's something very close to your needs already commercially available in stuctured light 3D scanning.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance these would be great if not for the price tag. I think ultimately I'm going to need to build my own scanner. I need a very basic system and the density of detail need not be large. Imagine a pothole on the road. I am going to put a sensor on a car going a max of 89km/hr. I need to be able to scan the roads as the car travels and get a map of the road traversed.

Comment: The simplest form of this is to just get distance measurements from the sensor to the ground. Ideally, I'd like to get a scan of the entire lane that the car is in. If not, then I just need a width as large as the car's tire treads.

Comment: Once these distance measurements are collected, I can send to a server for processing. At the server, I can use the points to make a map of the roads. This is the most basic form of this device. Can I get your advice on this? Do you think this is possible to make cheaply? I'd like to keep the cost of this under $200 if possible. I don't mind having to put in the hours myself to build this and I have the technical skills necessary to understand the physics and programming logic needed.